# java apache poi How to set two rows to always show

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

My goal is to make it so that my first two rows of a spreadhseet will ALWAYS show no matter how far down I scroll. But quite frankly, I have no idea how to do this or if this even possible using poi.

Could someone direct me to the right directions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your `Sheet` object, call the [`createFreezePane` method](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#createFreezePane%28int,%20int%29).

```
sheet.createFreezePane(0 /* columns */, 2 /* rows */);
```